# How can a shield winding in the transformer be helpful without fully covering the core?

Tags: transformer, emc, shielding

[This article](http://www.arcfn.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html) describes the Apple iPhone charger circuitry in great details. It mentions the *shield winding* in the flyback transformer. The *shield winding* is simply an extra most outer winding and the article claims that it filters out EMI.

However the transformer clearly has a core and it has so-called EQ design in which the core has huge parts not covered by the windings. Since the core contains the magnetic field I'd expect the core to "leak" it and since the shield winding doesn't fully cover the core I'd expect the *shield winding* to not be very efficient.

How does the shield winding help against EMI if it doesn't fully cover the transformer core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shield does not assist against EMI - its protects against ESI - although the two are liable to walk hand in glove in this case.

ie the shield is an **electrostatic** shield and reduces **capacitive** coupling
 and not an electromagnetic shield which would reduce magnetic coupling.
 Needless to say, an electromagnetic field would be a bad thing [tm] for the interior of a transformer.

The shield is effective wherever it places a grounded capacitively coupled sheet between any primary and secondary parts that would otherwise be capacitively coupled. Even imperfect couplig reduction is useful

[Electrostatic shields - Canada transformers](http://canadatransformers.ca/what-is-transformer-electrostatic-shield)

[image]

[Single layer winding as an electrostatic shield](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Isolation_Transformer_Simple_with_Dielectric_Barrier_and_Electrostatic_Shield.jpg)

[EE times - useful](http://www.eetimes.com/design/industrial-control/4014229/Electrical-noise-and-mitigation--Part-3--Shielding-and-grounding-cont--and-filtering-harmonics)

[Useful images](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=electrostatic+shield&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=cobkT6PBMenbmAXZtuGLCw&ved=0CIIBELAE&biw=1920&bih=1081)

Comment: In the Apple charger the shield winding is the most outer winding so both primary and secondary windings are inside the shield winding.

Comment: Presumably they are trying to reduce capacitive coupling of signal and noise to surrounding conductive materials in order to reduce the overall "electromagnetic footprint" and make achieving regulatory compliance easier. While the regulations talk about EMC (electromagnetic comptability) it's really about minimisation of cause and effects due to any form of electronic signals (electric, magnetic or electromagnetic).